# solution verification on diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

let $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &a  &a \\ 
 a&2  &0 \\ 
 1&0  &2 
\end{pmatrix}$  $a \in\mathbb{R}$  find for what values of $a$ is diagonalizable

Solution.
The characteristic polynomial is $ (2-t)(t^2-3t-a^2-a+2)$

it is enough to show that $t^2-3t-a^2-a+2$ has roots in $\mathbb{R}$

it has to be true that

$9-4(-a^2-a+2)\geq 0\Leftrightarrow a^2+a+1/4 \geq 0$ wich is true because $a^2+a+1/4=(a+1/2)^2\geq 0$

That means for every $a\in\mathbb{R}$ the matrix $A$ is diagonalizable.

I feel like I have miss something here, is this correct?

Comment: I didn't use the C-H theorem neither the minimum polynomial somehow.

Comment: Why is it enough to show that $t^2-3t-a^2-a+2$ has roots in $\Bbb R$? (You also have a typo in your algebra.)

Comment: If your characteritsic polynomial has *distinct* roots then you can say $A$ is diagonalizable. There are only $3$ values of $a$ when your characteristic polymomial doesn't have distinct roots; you can treat those cases separately. Also, $$a^2+a+1/4=(a+1/2)^2$$

Comment: Notice that
$$t^2-3t-a^2-a+2 = (t+(a-1)) \cdot (t-(a+2))$$  You have $t_1=2,t_2=1-a,t_3=a+2$ You should check if which $a$ values the algebraic multiplicity is equal to the geometry multiplicity.